# Getting data from Django website after logging in with requests

Tags: django, python-requests

I have logged with user credentials using the following code:

```
import requests

url_login='https://test.com/admin/'


user = 'test'
password = 'test'

headers = {
            # 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0',
            # 'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01',
            # 'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest',  # AJAX
            'Referer': 'https://test.com/admin/login/?next=/admin/',
        }

client = requests.session()
client.get(url_login)
csrftoken = client.cookies['csrftoken']
login_data = {'username':user,'password':password, 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':csrftoken, 'next': '/pecasRunLog/'}
print(login_data)
r1=client.post(url_login,data=login_data, headers=headers)
```

r1.status code returns 200 which seems to be fine.
But how can I proceed with fetching data from the pages available only for logged in users with requests. Tried this and that and it still returns log in page.

Comment: i guess you are trying to send data to backend. You can do this with Fetch API. Take a look here https://www.brennantymrak.com/articles/fetching-data-with-ajax-and-django.html. As for the ```only for logged in users``` you can store logged users data with sessions

Comment: The final thing I am interested in is getting data, not posting.